# How do I align these two shapes to form a tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to print a tree shape where the user inputs 4 different parameters. Branch height, branch width, stem height and stem width. I have two shapes that form the top part and bottom part of the tree but I can't seem to figure out how to put them together so that it looks like a tree. I figured that I need to calculate the width of the branch and deduct the stem from that but I'm not exactly sure. My output currently looks like this:

Any suggestions?

```
Enter height of the branches: 5
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
Enter width of the stem: 5
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****



def pyramid(height):
    for row in range(height):
        for count in range(height - row):
            print(end=" ")
        for count in range(2 * row + 1):
            print(end="*")
        print()

def square(width):
    for i in range(width):
        for j in range(width):
            print('*', end='')
        print()


height = int(input("Enter height of the branches: "))
pyramid(height)

width = int(input("Enter width of the stem: "))
square(width)
```

Comment: To align the stem you will need to add some spaces at the beginning of each line. How many spaces depends on the width of the branches, which in turn depends on the height of the tree. Try to figure out the relationship between height and width (1 level -> 1 width, 2 levels -> 3 width, etc.); each time you add two `*`, so it should be about the double, right? Then, the margin you need to put in the stem is half that width, minus half the width of the stem itself, so the center of the stem ends up in the middle. Note that, in this case, only odd-size stems can be perfectly centered.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that it only perfectly centers if the numbers are odd.

Comment: You should add some error checking in there that height is odd and width less than `2 * height + 1` etc :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`str.center(width\[, fillchar\])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.center):

```
def pyramid(height):
    for row in range(height):
        print(('*' * (2 * row + 1)).center((2 * height + 1)))

def square(width, height):
    for i in range(width):
        print(('*' * (width)).center((2 * height + 1)))

height = int(input("Enter height of the branches: "))
pyramid(height)

width = int(input("Enter width of the stem: "))
square(width, height)
```

Out:

```
C:\_\Python363-64\python.exe C:/Users/MrD/.PyCharm2018.2/config/scratches/scratch_75.py
Enter height of the branches: 5
     *     
    ***    
   *****   
  *******  
 ********* 
Enter width of the stem: 5
   *****   
   *****   
   *****   
   *****   
   *****   

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 2):

may be  try this :

```
    def pyramid(height):
        for row in range(height):
            for count in range(height - row):
                print(end=" ")
            for count in range(2 * row + 1):
                print(end="*")
            print()

    def square(width):
        if height % 2 == 0:
         space=int((height/2))*' '
        else:
         space=int((height/2)+1)*' '
        for i in range(width):
            print(end=space)
            for j in range(width):
                print('*', end='')
            print()


    height = int(input("Enter height of the branches: "))


    width = int(input("Enter width of the stem: "))
    pyramid(height)
    square(width)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add white spaces before each line of the stem that are enough to fill the height of the pyramid minus half the width of the stem:

```
def pyramid(height):
    for row in range(height):
        for count in range(height - row):
            print(end=" ")
        for count in range(2 * row + 1):
            print(end="*")
        print()

def square(width, pyramid_height):
    for i in range(width):
        print(' ' * (pyramid_height - width // 2), end='')
        for j in range(width):
            print('*', end='')
        print()


height = int(input("Enter height of the branches: "))
pyramid(height)

width = int(input("Enter width of the stem: "))
square(width, height)
```

Comment: There is `str.center` which is an out of the box way of doing this :)